# Android - how to change window?

Tags: android, focus

Iam new to android and trying to change window with the press of a button. I thought the following code would work, but when I add

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout2)
```

`;, (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);` suddenly becomes underlined red with the text  Unexpected cast to Button: layout tag was ImageButton

```
  final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your button Variable:

```
private Button home;
```

In the your `onCreate`, declare it:

```
home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_home);
home.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then your onClick should be something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.project.activityName"));
}
```